# Auto completion font size difference

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

I have two laptops both having VS 2015 installed (Win 8 and Win 7). 
Observing difference in fonts for the auto completion box.
Where should I change the font in order to get size as for the smaller font (first) example?

First:

[image]

Second:

[image]

Both have same setting in Completion Appearance i.e. Visual Studio IntelliSense font.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have set it also the same in `Tools -> Options -> Fonts and Colors -> Statement Completion`. Was set to Tahoma for some reason.
[image]